# react-particle-js not updating the number of particles

Tags: reactjs, particle.js

I have:

```
return (
  <Particles
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      zIndex: -1
    }}
    params={{
      number: {
        value: 400,
        density: {
          enable: true,
          value_area: 800
        }
      },
      line_linked: {
        enable: true,
        distance: 150,
        color: "#ffffff",
        opacity: 0.4,
        width: 1
      },
      "shape": {
        "type": "circle",
        "stroke": {
          "width": 0,
          "color": "#000000"
        },
        polygon: {
          nb_sides: 7
        }
      },
      "interactivity": {
        "detect_on": "canvas",
        "events": {
          "onhover": {
            "enable": true,
            "mode": "grab"
          },
          "onclick": {
            "enable": true,
            "mode": "push"
          },
          "resize": true
        },
        "modes": {
          "grab": {
            "distance": 400,
            "line_linked": {
              "opacity": 1
            }
          },
          "repulse": {
            "distance": 200,
            "duration": 0.4
          }
        }
      },
      "retina_detect": true
    }} />
```

No matter how high I make `number.value`, the number of particles on the screen just doesn't increase. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've missed to enclose this properties inside **particles**. Also remove the z-index property from styles or set it to **0** that will display the particles

```
particles: {
  number: {
    value: 400,
    density: {
      enable: true,
      value_area: 800
    }
  },
  line_linked: {
    enable: true,
    distance: 150,
    color: "#ffffff",
    opacity: 0.4,
    width: 1
  },
  "shape": {
    "type": "circle",
    "stroke": {
      "width": 0,
      "color": "#000000"
    },
    polygon: {
      nb_sides: 7
    }
  }
 },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
```

Comment: Hmmm - then how do I make it my background?